# What is the limit inferior and limit superior of sequence,$x_n=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\sin \left(\dfrac{n\pi}{3}\right),n\geq1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let,$x_n=(1-\frac{1}{n}) \sin(\frac{n\pi}{3}),n\geq1$.Then what is the limit inferior and limit superior if this sequence?

I know that the limit inferior of $x_n$ and limit superior of $x_n$ are respectively the smallest and the largest accumulation point.

Writing the sequence in the explicit form,

## {$x_1$,$x_2$,,$x_3$,$x_4$,$x_5$,$x_6$,$x_7$,...,...}

={$(1-\frac{1}{1}) \sin(\frac{1\pi}{3})$,$(1-\frac{1}{2}) \sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})$,$(1-\frac{1}{3}) \sin(\frac{3\pi}{3})$,$(1-\frac{1}{4}) \sin(\frac{4\pi}{3})$,$(1-\frac{1}{5}) \sin(\frac{5\pi}{3})$,$(1-\frac{1}{6}) \sin(\frac{6\pi}{3})$,$(1-\frac{1}{7}) \sin(\frac{7\pi}{3})$}={$0,\frac{1}{4}$,$(1-\frac{1}{n}) \sin(\frac{n\pi}{3}),...,...$}

={$0,\frac{1}{4}$,$\frac{-2}{3}$,$\frac{-3\sqrt3}{8}$,$\frac{-2\sqrt3}{5}$,$0$,$\frac{3\sqrt3}{7}$,$\frac{-7\sqrt3}{16}$,...,...}

Now i collected the subsequences;{$x_1$,$x_6$,$x_{11}$,$x_{16}$,$x_{17},,,$}={$0,0,0,0,...,...,...$}.

I got struck here.I'm unable to select other suitable subsequences of ($x_n$) by which we can choose the smallest and the largest accumulation point of the

Comment: Please write sine function as `\sin x` instead of `Sinx`.

Comment: Try the three subsequences given by $n=3k$, $n=3k+1$, and $n=3k-1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:What  do you mean by $k$,here?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Please refrain from adding commands that force display style such as `\dfrac` to the title. Display mode is simply not designed for use on the same line as normal text. Using it in titles results breaks visual continuity on the front page due to misaligned line heights and excess white spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that

$$\sin\frac{n\pi}3=\begin{cases}&0,&n=0,\,3\pmod 6\\{}\\&\cfrac{\sqrt3}2,&n=1,\,2\pmod3\\{}\\&-\cfrac{\sqrt3}2,&n=4,\,5\pmod 6\end{cases}$$

IT may also be worthwhile to take into account that $\;\left\{\left(1-\frac1n\right)\right\}\;$ is a descending sequence...

Comment: :It means $limsup(x_n)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ &$liminf(x_n)=\frac{-\sqrt3}{2}$?By the way excellent way of representation.

Comment: @PKStyles Yes, because $\;1-\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$ , so taking $\;n\,$'s with different values modulo $\;6\;$ will give us the different values we want. For example: $$\left(1-\frac1{6n+5}\right)\sin\frac{(6n+5)\pi}3\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

Comment: :Why had you chosen $(mod 6)$ particularly??

Comment: @PKStyles Because that's the way to obtain **all** the possible values...Remember that $\;\sin x\;$ is periodic $\;2\pi\;$ .